# Why is SELECT '1970-01-01T01:00:00.000' > '1970-01-01T01:00:00' = 1?

Tags: sqlite

Why is in sql lite '1970-01-01T01:00:00.000' bigger than '1970-01-01T01:00:00'

```
SELECT '1970-01-01T01:00:00.000' > '1970-01-01T01:00:00'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the rules for comparing two strings in sqlite is that if the strings contains the same characters *up to a point*, and only one of the strings contains more characters *after that point*, then that string comes first.

Same as this:

```
select 'aa' > 'a'
```

Comment: and what if one operator is a datetime-field?

Comment: @wutzebaer There is [no such thing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Comment: @wutzebaer A what now? That's not SQLite then.

Comment: That means DATETIME is just an alias for String?

Comment: SQLite does not have a DATETIME data type, in fact it does not have data types at all, it has "storage classes" and "type affinity". You can store whatever you want in all columns, regardless of how you declared them.

Comment: In any case, this question is about string comparison. I don't know all the rules for comparing values *of different types* in SQLite so I'm not going to even try to go into that territory, but this question is simple enough. Comparing two strings uses string comparison rules.

Comment: and what does it mean if i create a table `CREATE TABLE test(lastLearned DATETIME)` ? It does not throw an error

Comment: It creates a table with a column that has a "type name" of DATETIME and a type affinity of "NUMERIC". You can, however, store whatever you want into this column. The *functions* that deals with date operations knows how to handle this if you follow the supported formats but if you store a string into that column it is still a string. The fact that it can be automagically parsed by these functions to get a datetime value for the underlying operation for you does not lessen that fact.